# Searching for given entries in the registry using NSIS

Tags: registry, nsis

Basically the NSIS of my application sets a registry value called "path" in a key called `SOFTWARE\APPLICATION_NAME VERSION_NUMBER` which denotes where the application is currently installed. I am now trying to introduce the functionality of checking if previous version(s) of the application are installed and if so offer to use the previous settings. If there are multiple versions installed, the user would be able to choose which version he wants the settings taken from. The problem I am having is to search the registry for previously installed versions. As I include the VERSION_NUMBER, the key in which the path can be found changes for each version and therefore there is no "set in stone" search query.

So, for example if I had used from the start `SOFTWARE\APPLICATION_NAME` without the version as the location to set the path information this would be easy as I could just check if that registry value existed. An ideal solution would be to be able to search with wildcards and retrieve all paths that match (e.g `SOFTWARE\APPLICATION_NAME*`). I could indeed stop inserting the "VERSION_NUMBER" from now on but this would not allow users to keep their current config on the next release but rather on the release after next (and that's if they are updating from the most recent version in the first place).

I hope that my question is clear. Please let me know if there is anything I can clarify.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [EnumRegKey](http://anders_k.users.sourceforge.net/public/NSIS/2.46/Manual.html#enumregkey) and some basic string handling/comparisons...